# How can i explode this string?

Tags: php, explode

I have a string like this |casio|watch|men| in an xml. I want to explode this and i need output like this : $brand = "casio"; $cat = "watch";.

i used these codes but it doesnt helped me

```
<?php

$string = '|casio|watch|men|'; 

$string = explode('-',$string);

var_dump($string); 

echo $string[0]; 

echo $string[1];

?>
```

Comment: It looks like you want `explode('|', $string);`

Comment: yess it was a mistake and worked! ty

Answer (score 0):

your trying to separate the string using '-' while your string doesnt contain any... in your case you should explode the using '|' example

```
$string = explode('|',$string);
```

Comment: yess it was a mistake and worked! ty